# Unable to install Ubuntu 18.04 on a UEFI BIOS

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I am unable to install ubuntu 18.04 on a UEFI bios version Dell 7000 2-in-1 laptop as it freezes on the boot screen itself when I click ‘Install Ubuntu’. My laptop does not have any NVIDIA drivers still I face the boot screen freeze issue. Can somebody help? 
I have used Rufus to create live-stick with the GPT partition scheme as suggested for UEFI bios. My laptop is a 512 GB SSD.
Can I know if there are any specific UEFI settings?

Comment: Please go to https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04?app=products enter your Service Tag number. That will provide you with the model number and the laptop configuration. Please then click [edit] and paste that vital information into your question, as there are _many_ different 7000 2-in-1 laptop models.

Answer (score 2):

"*I have used Rufus to create live-stick with the GPT partition scheme*":  this is probably your problem.  The USB should not have a GPT partition table and should have an MBR partition scheme for boot compatibility.  The disk where you intend to install Ubuntu should, however, use the GPT partition scheme for a UEFI installation.

I suggest using [etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) as a no-nonsense option to write the .ISO to your USB.  Unlike rufus, it does not present you with choices that won't work.

Also consider the possibility that your USB device is corrupted, or that your download is corrupted.  Did you [verify the integrity of the downloaded .ISO](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17764/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-downloaded-ubuntu-cd) before writing it to the USB?

Comment: See Dell 7791 UEFI update & some settings
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2431450&page=3
Ubuntu 19.10 Provides Good Out-Of-The-Box Support For The Dell XPS 7390 Icelake Laptop
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=dell-xps7390-ubuntu1910&num=1
 & Dell XPS 15 Series 7590 (2019)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161456/how-to-run-ubuntu-on-new-dell-xps-15-7000-series-7590 & 
https://github.com/TillmannBerg/Ubuntu-Dell-XPS-15-2019 DELL Inspiron 15 7577 18.04 needed boot parameters
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2386049

Comment: @Nmath, the fact that OP managed to get to the "Install Ubuntu" prompt means that the problem has nothing to do with using GPT vs. MBR. If they got that far, it means that their target computer booted in pure UEFI mode. I agree that, to ensure dual BIOS + UEFI boot, it's better to use MBR over GPT, but in this specific case, this is clearly not the issue.

Comment: @Akeo can you post the solution as another answer?

Comment: I don't have a solution. I was just pointing out that the GPT vs MBR assertion was factually incorrect if the user managed to get to the installation screen. What happens after OP selects _Install Ubuntu_ seems like a Ubuntu incompatibility issue with their hardware, but not one I can venture an explanation for, let alone a workaround.