# Ubuntu fails to boot on Dell XPS 15 (7590)

Tags: boot, 18.04, 19.10, zfs, 20.04

I have tried this procedure w/ 18.04, 19.10, and 20.04 (Beta).

I am installing w/ Root on ZFS, using:

https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/wiki/Ubuntu-18.04-Root-on-ZFS

I wiped the entire disk (using Data Wipe in the BIOS), and then installed using the procedure outlined in the link above.  Everything goes smoothly (using LUKS encryption, disable secure boot in BIOS, using UEFI boot).  No problems.

I reboot at the end of the installation, I get the GRUB menu.  I hit enter to boot into Ubuntu, and the screen goes blank, and that's it.

I can re-boot, and I get back through the DELL logo, and get the GRUB menu aain, and that's all.

Help?

EDIT:

More information:

It was difficult (nearly impossible) to see, cause the laptop has a 4k screen, aand the default font is exceedingly small, but I noticed that after full install, and first boot, the GRUB menu only had one line in it, 'UEFI Firmware Update'.

Also, as part of this process, when I did:

```
update-initramfs -u -k all
```

and

```
update-grub
```

there was no error in either of these, but neither one produced any output, and it didn't fell like anything happened.

Further edit:

Even more info:

I'm re-running install from scratch.  When I do:

```
root@ubuntu:/# update-grub
```

I get:

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.4.0-25-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu
Warning: Couldn't find any valid initrd for dataset rpool/ROOT/ubuntu.
Warning: didn't find any valid initrd or kernel.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
```

Not sure what the two Warning lines above mean, but it seems they are related?

Comment: While not ZFS, these are Dell issues: Dell XPS 15 Series 7590 (2019)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161456/how-to-run-ubuntu-on-new-dell-xps-15-7000-series-7590
https://github.com/TillmannBerg/Ubuntu-Dell-XPS-15-2019
Linus - Do not use ZFS on Linux
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linus-Says-No-To-ZFS-Linux & 
https://linux.slashdot.org/story/20/01/19/0059251/what-linus-torvalds-gets-wrong-about-zfs#comments

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look.

Comment: All the issues listed above are related to things that don't work post-installation.  No hints as to why installation would fail....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue.
Looks like The initrd is not generated.

```
# ls -l /boot/initrd*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 avril 22 13:03 /boot/initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.4.0-26-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 avril 22 13:03 /boot/initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.4.0-26-generic
```

Comment: Looks like you need to use `update-initramfs -c -k all` instead of `update-initramfs -u -k all`.

Comment: Thanks!  This worked for me!  If you enter it as an answer, I'll upvote it and accept it!

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, the initrd did not get created by debootstrap.
All the -u flag does is updating existing initramfs. Hence, you have to use the -c flag first in order to create it : `update-initramfs -c -k all`.

Comment: Thanks Yamashita.  After I asked you to enter this as an answer, I realized you were the author that that, so I upvoted and accepted that answer.  Sorry for the confusion, and thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. I am a newbie at this askubuntu thing so I am happy everything turned out okay in the end. Good luck with your ZFS testing.