# Fresh Ubuntu 20.04 installation won't boot after GRUB and stuck in boot loop

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, grub-efi

I made USB bootable using Universal USB Installer on another windows 10 PC.
Installed using the "Ubuntu (Safe Graphics)" option because the "Ubuntu" option freezes the wizard before installation.
Opted for third party software and proprietary drivers.
Opted "Required Password for login"
Installed successfully

On reboot and selecting "Ubuntu" on GRUB menu, it simply restarts, shows bios logo (dell), and again displays GRUB menu.

I tried to get into recovery mode but it simply reboots after printing "Loading initial ramdisk..."

I also tried following but nothing worked:

- Added modprobe.blacklist=nouveau at the end of the line that starts with 'linux' after pressing 'e' at grub menu
- Added nouveau.modeset=0 at the end of the line that starts with 'linux' after pressing 'e' at grub menu

My BIOS Settings and Specs:

- Secure Boot = Disabled
- Laptop: Dell Inspiron 7567
- Memory: 8GB
- GPU: NVIDIA GTX 1050 Ti 4GB
- CPU: Intel i7

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you boot recovery mode, second line in grub menu, to a terminal? Similar systems: Dell XPS 15 Series 7590 (2019)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161456/how-to-run-ubuntu-on-new-dell-xps-15-7000-series-7590
DELL Inspiron 15 7577 18.04 needed boot parameters
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2386049
Post installation issues Ubuntu 18.04-Dell inspiron 7559
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072382/post-installation-issues-ubuntu-18-04-dell-inspiron-7559
Post report from this also:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair