# Dualboot RST problem

Tags: dual-boot, dell, xps, rst

so I've already installed Ubuntu as dual-boot few times in the past, but this is something new for me and I'm not sure, if I really know what I'm doing.

I have Dell XPS 7590 and followed the instructions on [this site](https://www.dell.com/support/article/sk-sk/sln301754/how-to-install-ubuntu-and-windows-8-or-10-as-a-dual-boot-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en).

I actually switched the first set up the partition and then went into the boot menu. There, in the Boot Sequence options, I didn't find anything in the Boot List Option, so I didn't touch it. Then, in the Advanced Boot Option, I also didn't find the "Enable Legacy Option ROMs". The only thing I did was to disable the Secure Boot (what lead to Windows not being able to boot without BitLocker recovery code).

After that I ran one-time boot from `UEFI: SanDisk, Partition 1`. I didn't get any "Try Ubuntu" option, only `Ubuntu`, `Ubuntu (safe graphics)`, `OEM install (for manufacturers)`, `Boot from next volume` and `UEFI Firmware Settings`; so I went for the `Ubuntu` option.

After that, "Checking disks" took place, and then I was able to start the installation. I chose the language, keyboard layout and wireless connection.

And then, I got the "Turn off RST" message: "This computer uses Intel RST (Rapid Storage Technology). You need to turn off RST before installing Ubuntu. For instructions, open this page on a phone of other device: [help.ubuntu.com/rst](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347)

I would follow the guide, but I'm afraid, that something could go horribly wrong. Do you guys have any recommendations or advices?

Thanks.

Edit:

Does anyone have any experiences with [this guide](https://medium.com/@tylergwlum/my-journey-installing-ubuntu-18-04-on-the-dell-xps-15-7590-2019-756f738a6447)?

Still thanks.

Comment: That is standard with all Dell and many other systems. You do need to install the ACHI drivers into Windows first if dual booting. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161456/how-to-run-ubuntu-on-new-dell-xps-15-7000-series-7590

Comment: @oldfred, thank you, but I don't really see how this link relates to ACHI drivers

Comment: I thought you had info on how to change to AHCI from Intel RST. Link was for other Dell issues on your model and some possible fixes. Windows AHCI instructions - some have found safeboot method better
https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Dell-M-2-FAQ-regarding-AHCI-vs-RAID-ON-Storage-Drivers-M-2-Lanes/td-p/5072571 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and here's what I found. First, the dededit solution did not work for me and, as always, you should try this at your own risk and back up your system before trying. just to be safe! Here's the workaround.

- Shrink your HD space, using the Windows disk tool, to whatever size you're giving Ubuntu
- Boot into your bios
- Change storage (under configuration) to AHCI. It will give you a msg saying that your disk may be deleted but it did not delete anything for me. WINDOWS WILL NOT BOOT UNDER AHCI. THIS IS NORMAL
- Insert your bootable usb
- Reboot your system from the usb (hold down the f12 key when you power up and choose usb)
- Ubuntu will start up and you can run the install. You will get to the part in the installation where it's going to ask if you want to install the full or minimal version of Ubuntu. You choose and hit continue.
- THIS IS WHERE YOU SHOULD SEE THE OPTION TO INSTALL UBUNTU ALONGSIDE WINDOWS. IT WILL NOT SHOW UP UNTIL AFTER THE PREVIOUS STEP
- Choose yes and it will automatically choose the partition you created before. Finish the install and reboot.
- Now you will get a boot menu and you choose Ubuntu and finish the install.

The boot menu will give you an option to enter the bios set up. IF YOU WANT TO RUN WINDOWS AGAIN YOU HAVE TO SWITCH BACK TO BST AND REBOOT.

And that's it!!!! Hope it helps!

Comment: PS: In order to get back to BST you reset to default settings in the UEFI

Comment: Yeah you're right, I also thought about this, but at the time I already had reinstalled Windows with AHCI, because I found Dell OS Recovery tool to reinstall and had all my important stuff backed up, so it was the easy way out. I also earlier found some ways to reconfigure Windows to use RST without reinstallation, but wasn't brave enough to try it and convinced about the reliability. But now I at least don't have to switch between RST and AHCI :)